# Searching String or StringBuilder with a pattern range /start/ /end/

Tags: c#, performance

I want to create a function (w/ a set of helper functions if needed) in C# that would perform a similar thing as `awk '/start/,/end/' file` - except that it would include all the last matches, rather than terminating on the first.

Lets say we have:

```
# cat text
"13:08:30:5276604 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:5736962 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:6227343 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:6757752 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:7208103 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:7668739 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:8129079 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
```

Expected:

```
"13:08:30:6227343 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:6757752 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:7208103 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:7668739 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
```

AWK output:

```
# awk '/13:08:30:62/,/13:08:30:7/' text
"13:08:30:6227343 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:6757752 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
"13:08:30:7208103 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M"
```

I initially thought that I might just get a regex match by two conditions `pattern_1 | pattern_2` however this will not work if there are values in between the matching values.

I also discovered that C# StringBuilder class does not have `.indexOf()` and `.lastIndexOf()` methods (I have a bit more experience in JAVA, so was thinking to use these untill I saw C# not having them). Since I don't have these methods and would need to possibly implement them, I wanted to ask if this is the approach to go? This section even suggests to use String if extensive searching is needed: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Searching) - and I can certainly use that as well. I chose to use StringBuilder because the string concatenation is performed constantly, should I use `stringbuilder` type when building the string (a lot of concatenation), but then convert to `string` type when searching?

I would also like this to be performant and it would be awesome to hear suggestions how to make it as such. General guidance and implementation details are appreciated.

Comment: How specific is your problem? Should this only work for this special case or should it work in the same scope as awk does?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is for _building_ the string.  First build it, then generate the entire string and use `String` functions to search.

Comment: @MetaColon - more generality would be desirable than just a specific case. I would specify it as: "given two patterns that exist inside a utf8 string find the text that starts with the first pattern and ends with the second." The additional requirement for including the entire line for the /end/ pattern can be added. @D Stanley - it is always good to get a confirmation that you are on the right track, thanks.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius RegEx should be suitable for that task.

Answer (score 0):

If you would need to process a potential large file you better use a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and process it per line using the [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method. That prevents that you end up with the complete file in memory, as you probably would when using a StringBuilder. By using the abstract [TextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx) on the implementation you can use both a string as a (file)stream.

To check for the begin an end matches you can use the [Regex class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx). It's [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns an instance with a `Success` property which will be true when a match is found.

To achieve the logic you're after I reckoned there are three states: before we found the begin, before we found the end, while we still found the end. I opted to implement this in an iterator as by using the [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword as that would give me the state machine almost for free.

Here is the implementation:

```
void Main()
{
    // use a streamreader to read characters
    // the .ctor accpets an Encoding as second parameter
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(@"sample.txt"))
    {
        ReadFromBeginToEnd("13:08:30:62","13:08:30:7",sr);
    }

    var text =@"
13:08:30:6227343 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M
13:08:30:6757752 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M
13:08:30:7208103 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M
13:08:30:7668739 Main: 41044 - 48.7617 M-- Other PIDS 2 - 79.1016 M";
    using(var sr = new StringReader(text))
    {
        ReadFromBeginToEnd("13:08:30:62","13:08:30:7", sr);
    }
}

// enumerate over the lines from the streamreader
// accepting two regexes, start and end
IEnumerable<string> FromBeginToEnd(TextReader rdr, Regex start, Regex end)
{
   // 1st state
   var line = rdr.ReadLine(); // initial read, null means we're done
   // read the lines until we hit our start match
   while(line != null && !start.Match(line).Success) 
   {
      // don't return these lines
      line = rdr.ReadLine();    
   }
   // 2nd state
   // read the lines while we didn't hit our end match
   while(line != null && !end.Match(line).Success) 
   {
      // return this line to the caller
      yield return line;
      line = rdr.ReadLine();    
   }
   // 3rd state
   // read the lines while we find our end match
   while(line != null && end.Match(line).Success) 
   {
      // return this line to the caller
      yield return line;
      line = rdr.ReadLine();    
   }
   // iterator is done
   yield break;
}

// take a start and end string that can be compiled to a regex
// and a file (fullpath)
void ReadFromBeginToEnd(string start, string end, TextReader reader) 
{
    // loop over the lines that mach the criteria
    // FromBeginToEnd is our custom enumerator
    foreach(var line in FromBeginToEnd(reader, new Regex(start), new Regex(end)))
    {
       // write to standard out
       // but this can be an StreamWriter.WriteLine as well.
       Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```